# nextcloud installed with docker shows Internal Server Error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, nextcloud

Nextcloud and mariadb were installed through docker-compose using the nextcloud official image posted on the docker hub. At first it ran fine, but at some point I get the following error:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=a1234!
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=a1234!
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=taeil
      - MYSQL_USER=taeil

  app:
    image: nextcloud
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    restart: always
```

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator if this error reappears multiple times, please include the technical details below in your report.
More details can be found in the server log.
```

Container log.

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Feb 25 06:22:26.247273 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.3.15 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 25 06:22:26.247325 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:29:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:29:25 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:30:16 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:30:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:31:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:31:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:32:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:32:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:33:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:33:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:34:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:34:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:35:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:35:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:36:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:36:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:37:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:37:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:38:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:38:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:39:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:39:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:40:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:40:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:41:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:41:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:42:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:42:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:43:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:43:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:44:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:44:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:45:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:45:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:46:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:46:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:47:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:47:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:23 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:34 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:35 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:35 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:36 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:36 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:36 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:48:37 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:26 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:26 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:26 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:27 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:28 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:28 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
172.18.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020:06:49:28 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 503 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
```

Log written inside container.

```
root@658b066e61eb:/var/www/html/data# cat nextcloud.log 
{"reqId":"bZA84C2ahOfIiE5TUmlb","level":2,"time":"2020-02-25T02:18:05+00:00","remoteAddr":"172.18.0.1","user":"--","app":"appstoreFetcher","method":"POST","url":"/index.php","message":"Could not connect to appstore: cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36","version":"18.0.1.3"}
{"reqId":"6bFnYDSahoUE6pPvElgg","level":2,"time":"2020-02-25T02:18:29+00:00","remoteAddr":"172.18.0.1","user":"keti","app":"appstoreFetcher","method":"GET","url":"/settings/apps/list","message":"Could not connect to appstore: cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36","version":"18.0.1.3"}
{"reqId":"6bFnYDSahoUE6pPvElgg","level":2,"time":"2020-02-25T02:18:39+00:00","remoteAddr":"172.18.0.1","user":"keti","app":"appstoreFetcher","method":"GET","url":"/settings/apps/list","message":"Could not connect to appstore: cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36","version":"18.0.1.3"}
```

Looking at the result of error 28, it is a timeout error and I don't know what is wrong.

I restarted docker with the systemctl command, deleted the docker image and the container and ran it again, but I keep getting the error.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: is the environment exposed to a good amount of load or is it a local test setup with little traffic?

Comment: Yes local test setup. At first, things started to go wrong.

Comment: Initially, the error continued while connecting to mariadb, so I tried several things.

The ip address of the db connection is 10.0.xx: 3306, which is the ip address of the computer, so I tried to delete it and try to install it again. The same error still occurs.

Comment: See _/var/www/html/config/config.php_ in the nextcloud container. Do the IP addresses there match the IP address of your host? Assuming the nextcloud container is connected to the _bridge_ interface.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have resolved the issue already. However I faced recently with the same issue and found [the solution](https://blog.samcater.com/fix-workaround-rpi4-docker-libseccomp2-docker-20/).

The reason is that nextcloud moves on Alpine Linux. Their Alpine variant is not compatible with Raspberry Pi 4 devices in case of:

- You are running a version of Docker prior to 19.04.
- You are running an outdated libseccomp2 library.

If it's the case you should update incompatible parts. Docker update should not be tricky. The steps for libseccomp2 are also well documented, as this has been a problem on multiple platforms (not just RPI4). The provided [link](https://blog.samcater.com/fix-workaround-rpi4-docker-libseccomp2-docker-20/) describes the way you could update them.

In my case image nextcloud:22 works well. I updated only libseccomp2 library and it was enough.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29924599)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set resource quotas for your containers. It might be that your database is consuming too much of your overall resources. You can find information on how to set up memory quotas here

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: mem_limit: 1000000000
    memswap_limit: 2000000000
    mem_reservation: 512m
    privileged: true